Issues with installing pod after installing react-native-onesignal: RuntimeError - `PBXGroup` attempted to initialize an object with unknown
After installing react-native-onesignal
I got this error
RuntimeError - `PBXGroup` attempted to initialize an object with unknown ISA `PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup` from attributes: 
{
  "isa"=>"PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup", 
  "exceptions"=>["0B2BF25A2CE09BA200A86A8F"], 
  "explicitFileTypes"=>{}, 
  "explicitFolders"=>[], 
  "path"=>"OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension", 
  "sourceTree"=>"<group>"
}


This error occurs when there's an incompatibility with the project file structure, specifically with a PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup that's not properly recognized.
Here's how to fix it:

Close Xcode completely
Find your .xcodeproj file in Finder (its is usually found in the ios folder)
Open the project.pbxproj file in a text editor
Search for "PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup"
Replace "PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup" with "PBXGroup"
Reopen Xcode

This should resolve the error since PBXGroup is the standard group type that Xcode expects. The PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup appears to be an invalid or deprecated group type.
Edit your pod file
  # ... other configurations ...
  
  pod 'react-native-onesignal', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-onesignal'

  # If you have a notification service extension, include:
  target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
    pod 'OneSignalXCFramework', '>= 3.0.0', '< 4.0'
  end
end

then run this
pod deintegrate
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf Podfile.lock
pod install

And if you get this error
[!] [Xcodeproj] Xcode project version (70) is higher than the latest supported by xcodeproj (63).
All you have to do is

Close Xcode completely
Find your .xcodeproj file in Finder (its is usually found in the ios folder)
Open the project.pbxproj file in a text editor
change  objectVersion = 63; to  objectVersion = 70;

Then run
pod install

"change objectVersion = 70; to objectVersion = 70;"
What is the change here exactly?
